# Google Analytics non-interact Attribute

Tags: android, ios, web, google-analytics

I am using the native google analytics SDKs in iOS and Android projects. Recently i noticed that the web API provides a way to track "non-interact" events:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#nonInteraction

However, the native SDKs do not allow to track events using this attribute. Can anybody explain why and how something like non-interact could be tracked using the native SDKs?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a lot of searching for a documentation for iOS i found this syntax:

[builder set:@"1" forKey:kGAINonInteraction];

taken from:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/enhanced-ecommerce

hope that helped.