# Can I force a session to end when my iOS app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

How do I force a session to end when my iOS app is backgrounded so that a new session is created even if the user reopens the app within 30 minutes of backgrounding it?  The v2 SDK had instructions on how to do this but I can't find anything similar in the v3 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass [session control](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions) = 'end' field in a [nonInteractive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682599/google-analytics-non-interact-attribute) hit when your app goes to background.

[How to listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857485/iphone-4-sdk-detect-return-from-background-mode) to when it goes background.